# Can I set up Paypal recurring payments on Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: commerce

Like the title suggests,
I am using Paypal for provide an apparent 'Trustworthy' service to my customers.
I offer a flat-price cleaning service.
I would like to offer a weekly, fortnightly and monthly service to my current 'products' at different discount rates on the original product.
can someone help me perform this?

Answer (score 1):

The only existing module-based solution is [Commerce SP](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_sp) plus [Commerce SP PayPal](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_sp_paypal).

The latter is in dev at the moment, but I've found it to work pretty well, albeit with a few minor business-specific alterations.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding a product pricing rule, checkout this video http://vimeo.com/22625018, nothing to do with recurring payments here :)